# SQL Server does not failback to the primary node

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, clustering, failover, windows-server

We are running SQL Server 2008 R2 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 two-node cluster.

My choice of machine is primary, and the secondary is just a low-end machine for contingency planing.

We had a failover the last day during night time and when I came to the office the next morning, I noticed that SQL Server service did not failback to the primary machine although it came back online.

All settings seems to be in place:

1. Attachment 1 shows the general tab of SQL Server service properties dialog box from Server Manager - > Failover Cluster Manager. Both machines are checked, **primary being at the top**.

   [image]
2. Attachment 2 shows failover tab of the same dialog box. Immediate failback is activated.

   [image]

How can I modify these settings so that whenever the primary comes back, system will failback onto it.

Comment: I think it's because you have both nodes as the preferred owners. That means it won't favor one over the other. Try un-ticking the secondary node.

Comment: I suspected that as the culprit too but did not want to go ahead and untick without being 100% sure about the consequences because it is prod environment and I have no option to test it first. Any input about the complications of leaving the checkbox of the second node unchecked is appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't say for certain as this isn't really my area. I can certainly say though, that in my situation I only have one node as the preferred node *but* I don't have automatic failback enabled. Normal failover works as you'd expect (2012 R2 though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a virtual lab environment simulating a clustered network where I unticked one of the nodes as the preferred owner. I can confirm that whenever the ticked node goes offline, the unticked one comes into play and the system failbacks onto the ticked node once it comes online again.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks for doing the leg-work on this one.